# How can I import a module in node.js and socket.io?

Tags: node.js, import, module, socket.io

I'm new in socket.io and I learn node.js as well. I try to import a module in node.js and socket.io but it doesn't work. The server stops working.

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const counter = require('./counter');

var io = require('socket.io')(server,{});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket)
{
   counter();
});
```

counter.js

```
const counter = () => {
  let time = 20;
  let countdown = setInterval(update, 1000);

  function update() {
   let sec = time % 60;
   io.sockets.emit(`${sec}`);
   time--;
   if (sec == 0) {
    io.sockets.emit('Time is over');
    clearInterval(countdown);
    }
  }
}
module.exports = counter
```

counter() is working outside the io.on but I need to work inside. Is there any solution for this? I'm not sure what I should import in counter.js that the socket works.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? One global counter for all users or a timer per user? When you say "the server stops working", do you get an error? A word of advice: try getting it working without the extra file, then add the extra file in at the end when it's just a simple import problem. Otherwise, you're trying to solve too many problems at the same time.

Comment: One global counter for all users. I didn't get any error, just stop working. I don't want to put all codes in one file. I'd like to import counter.js to app.js

Comment: I know you want two files in the long run, but I'm suggesting that you do it in steps in the short run so you can avoid taking on too many problems for yourself at once. First, get the counter working, second, once it's working, move it to another file. On each tick, broadcast the count to all users connected to sockets. When should the counter start? Right now you're starting a new counter for each user.

Comment: All working. Next step to move this file to the app.js.

Comment: Can you show the working version so I can understand your intent? It seems to have been lost in translating to multiple files, because the code here doesn't make much sense if you just want a single counter for all users.

Comment: Yeah, that makes more sense. Keep `counter()` outside of the connection callback, then expose `io` to the `counter` module so it can broadcast, or provide a callback so it's more generalized. BTW, `setTimeout` doesn't provide accurate time. I suggest using a `Date`.

Comment: I need inside of the connection

Comment: Why? What are you doing with it inside the connection? I thought you said you want one counter for all users.

Comment: To show in the front end with socket.io. Now it's only showing in the console

Comment: I'm not sure how that's possible. You don't have any `console.log`s other than the one that lets you know your server is running. You can broadcast to clients from the timer without running that code from the `.on` closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I would imagine your main issue is that 'counter' has no idea what 'io' is. Try passing in io to counter.

```
const counter = (io) => {  //<--- add io
  let time = 20;
  let countdown = setInterval(update, 1000);

  function update() {
   let sec = time % 60;
   io.sockets.emit(`${sec}`);
   time--;
   if (sec == 0) {
    io.sockets.emit('Time is over');
    clearInterval(countdown);
    }
  }
}
```

This adds an argument to your counter function that we can access inside the function. When you call your 'counter' function- we'll pass the io object to it so that the function has access to the object like so:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket)
{
   counter(io); // <--- add io
});
```

You can check out a working example of what you would like to accomplish here:

https://replit.com/@brandonetter/OrangeredShamelessVendor#index.js